# Vue 1.0.4 js gives error on class binding: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

I'm new in Vue, and I try to do a small PoC, but I don't know why, I got an error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**.

My html:

```
<div id="configuration">
....
    <div class="list-group config-list">
        <a
            v-for="item in configurationList"
            v-on:click="SelectItem(item)"
            class="list-group-item"
            v-bind:class="'active': isActive(item)"
            href="#">{{ FormatItemType(item) }}
        </a>
    </div>
....
</div>
```

Vue definition:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#configuration",
    data:
    {
        configurationList:
        [
            { Id: "100", Version: 1, Type: "TestType.TestType100" },
            { Id: "200", Version: 2, Type: "TestType.TestType200" },
            { Id: "300", Version: 3, Type: "TestType.TestType300.Roles" }
        ],
        configurationData:
        {
            Id: "100", Version: 1, Type: "TestType.TestType100", Content: "TestType.TestType100"
        },
        computed:
        {
            isActive: function (configurationListItem)
            {
                return choosenConfigurationListItem.Type == configurationListItem.Type;
            }
        },

        choosenConfigurationListItem: null
    },

    methods:
    {
        FormatItemType: ... not important
        SelectItem: function (configurationListItem)
        {
            this.choosenConfigurationListItem = configurationListItem;
        }
    }
})
```

If I delete **v-bind:class="'active': isActive(item)"** entry, there is no error. Is the sntax wrong, or does missing something?

Thanks in advance,
Detonator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried :class="{active: isActive(item)}" syntax?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer.Your syntax seems good, just isActive method is not called

Comment: I've fixed a little your code, check it please:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/tzgnapyc/3/

Comment: This is not working, I checked the fiddle. isActive is a function with parameter, you use it as a property. But, your previous answer helped me to solve the problem related to the syntax error. Otherwise, the main problem here was the IsActive function. It has no need to be computed value, it should be in the methods area. Thanks...

Comment: I don't think that you can pass any arg to computed method... Why not try to create a function with the computed data?